# Current in a short circuit

Tags: electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Well,if theoretically we say the value of a resistor is zero then will there be any heat dissipation across the resistor(because heat is produced only when there's a resistance to the flow of current.)If there's zero resistance then won't current simply go on flowing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does voltage drop occurs with zero load and zero resistance](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144907/)

Comment: Also related: [Power dissipated on internal resistance of short-circuited voltage source](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88760/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the resistance is zero, voltage drop is null, and all the current the generator can provide flows in the conductor.

This happends for example in SQUIDs (superconductor devices with a circular form), where current has been measured flowing for several months continously because of the near-zero resistance of the device